# How do I reset the fade effect on ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, settings, samsung-galaxy-ace

I recently installed ICS on my Samsung Galaxy Ace and I have accidentally enabled the fade effect throughout the phone, but now I cannot find the setting that I changed. I don't want to perform a factory reset. Does anyone know how to reset this fade effect on ICS? The effect is being applied throughout the phone, while displaying system popups, pressing menu buttons etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to SETTINGS > DEVELOPER OPTIONS and change WINDOW ANIMATION and TRANSITION ANIMATION to 1x for the default or 0 for the speediest UI response

Comment: thanks a lot man, you saved me from doing factor reset, thanks a lot